# System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdownlistfor

I am getting a run time exception as shown below, compiling the source code doesn't show any issues. The issue is not happening for @html.TextBoxFor(), why is this happening for DropDownListFor?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EView.EStatusId, @Model.EView.EStatus)
public class EView
{
    #region Constructor

    public EView()
    {
        this.EDataView = new EDataViewModel();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int EStatusId { get; set; }

    public EDataViewModel EDataView { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem>  EStatus
    {
        get {
            SelectListItem item = null;
            List<SelectListItem> status = null;

            status = new List<SelectListItem>();
            item = new SelectListItem();

            item.Text = "Open";
            item.Value = "1";
            status.Add(item);

            item = new SelectListItem();

            item.Text = "Closed";
            item.Value = "2";
            status.Add(item);
            return status;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

`System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<EApp.ViewModels.AdminViewModel>` does not contain a definition for `DropDownListFor` and the best extension method overload `System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)` has some invalid arguments

Comment: Show some code please!

Comment: Have you checked my answer? I am binding the dropdown list considering you are passing `@model YourNamespace.EView` to view and this is working fine for me. Let me know what your are passing to view.

Comment: I was able to figure out the resolution to the issue. My View model was not having the System.Web.Mvc namespace instead it was having the namespace System.Web.WebPages.Html, The missing of System.Web.Mvc namespace cause the issue "does not contain a definition for DropDownListFor and the best extension method overload".. Anyways thanks Rahul for your help :-)

Answer (score 4):

This error can be caused by using the wrong SelectListItem type. I inadvertently selected the wrong namespace when I hit Ctrl-. on my unresolved SelectListItem type declaration. I selected System.Web.WebPages.Html instead of System.Web.Mvc. This resulted in the semi-cryptic run-time error in the View. The solution is to make sure you are using the correct SelectListItem type in your Controller, ViewModel, etc., by either using the correct namespace in your using statement, or by fully qualifying the SelectListItem type, if needed. (Hopefully it is not needed...)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late I know, but how about dropping the '@' in front of Model.EView.EStatus?

So:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EView.EStatusId, Model.EView.EStatus)
```

Comment: That doesn't matter in the slightest. When in a C# context (so, after the initial `@` in Razor), an at sign (`@`) is used to escape identifiers that violate C# syntax, such as `public class @class { }`. You can prepend it freely to any identifier.

Comment: Cheers CodeCaster. You're right. I reckon I was thinking of using '@'s inbetween curly-bracketed code blocks - i.e. how Razor doesn't like you nesting code blocks themselves.